# how to change actions in unity with the new input system using a script?

Tags: 3d

how to change actions in unity with the new input system using a script ?

My goal was to create a script to change the control in Unity using the New Input System(1.5.1) which when the UI button "Left" is clicked, would wait for the keyboard or gamepad button to be pressed and then the character would move to the left of the button we pressed

I use versions of :
Unity - 2021.3.21f1
Input System - 1.5.1

And since I couldn't figure out the unity documentation and am not well versed in the New Input System, I tried to ask ChatGPT, but he didn't help me.

My request For ChatGPT:

"Create a Unity script that allows the player to toggle between keyboard and gamepad control schemes in a 2D platformer game. The script should use the Input System package version 1.5.1 and be compatible with all gamepads. The player should be able to assign new keys or gamepad buttons to the following player actions: right, left, jump, crouch, creep, and hit. The script should provide visual feedback (such as a message or animation) to indicate when it is waiting for the player to input the new key or gamepad button.

The script should include the following features:

A UI button that resets the control scheme to its default settings.
A UI button that saves the player's control scheme preferences so that they are retained across gameplay sessions.
The ability to add custom text to the UI buttons using TextMeshPro."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.